# Use of Laplace transform to solve initial value problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

## --Short Explanation:

I have to say I am going crazy with this problem as it does not give me the same as the suggested solution in the book:

**Problem:**

$y''-7y'+10y=9\cos{t}+7\sin{t}$

$y(0)=5$, $y'(0)=-4$

## --Long Explanation

So, I've been trying over and over, and then I surrendered and tried finding the solution online, I did find [a solution](http://openstudy.com/updates/51fddbe5e4b05ca7841f8988) on a website called openstudy.com, **this solution gives exactly the same as in the book answers** but I am just not following it, here is what I found:

\begin{align}
y''-7y'+10y &=9\cos t+7\sin t\qquad y(0)=5, y'(0)=-4\\
s^2Y-sy(0)-y'(0)-7(sY-y(0))+10Y &=\frac{9s}{s^2+1}+\frac7{s^2+1}\\
s^2Y-7sY+10Y-5s+4+35 &=\frac{9s+7}{s^2+1}\\
(s^2-7s+10)Y(s) &=\frac{9s+7}{s^2+1}+5s-39\\
(s^2-7s+10)Y(s) &=\frac{9s+7+5s(s^2+1)-39(s^2+1)}{s^2+1}\\
(s^2-7s+10)Y(s) &=\frac{9s+7+5s^3+1+5s-39s^2-39}{s^2+1}\\
(s-5)(s-2)Y(s) &=\frac{5s^3-39s^2+14s-32}{s^2+1}\\
Y(s) &=\frac{5s^3-39s^2+14s-32}{(s-5)(s-2)(s^2+1)}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
Y(s) &=\frac{5s^3-39s^2+14s-32}{(s-5)(s-2)(s^2+1)}=\frac{A}{s-5}+\frac{B}{s-2}+\frac{Cs+D}{s^2+1} \\
& A(s-2)(s^2+1)+B(s-5)(s^2+1)+(Cs+D)(s-2)(s-5) \\
&=A(s^3-2s^2+s-2)+B(s^3-5s^2+s-5)+(Cs+D)(s^2-7s+10) \\ 
&=(A+B)s^3+(-2A-5B)s^2+(A+B)s+(-2A-5B)+(Cs^3+(-7C+D)s^2+(10C-7D)s+10D) \\ &=(A+B+C)s^3-(2A+5B+7C-D)s^2+(A+B+10C-7D)s-(2A+5B+10D)
\end{align}

hence we get:$$A+B+C=5\\2A+5B+7C-D=39\\A+B+10C-7D=14\\2A+5B+10D=32$$taking the difference between the second and fourth we get:$$7C-11D=7$$and the first and third gets us:$$9C-7D=9$$eliminating between these two yields (C=1,D=0) and from this we find:$$A+B=4\\2A+5B=32$$hence (A=-4,B=8) and ultimately we conclude:$$Y(s)=-\frac4{s-5}+\frac8{s-2}+\frac{s}{s^2+1}$$

## --What I do not understand

Just right before "hence we get:"

\begin{align}
& (A+B)s^3+(-2A-5B)s^2+(A+B)s+(-2A-5B)+(Cs^3+(-7C+D)s^2+(10C-7D)s+10D) \\ &=(A+B+C)s^3-(2A+5B+7C-D)s^2 +(A+B+10C-7D)s -(2A+5B+10D)
\end{align}

How the heck did that $+10D$ just turned into a $-10D$?, am I just forgetting something?.

Now if this solution is wrong, then how do I go into obtaining the same result, I obtain something completely different. Is the book wrong?

**Thank you so much, really.**

Comment: For what it's worth, the partial fraction decomposition looks correct. See this WolframAlpha working out of it: http://bit.ly/1QgqLYr

As for where their algebra goes awry ....

Comment: All right @SimonS , thank you so much for that information, so the book is definitely not wrong, I must be wrong, damn, now I feel like I want to post my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ... so put the sign back in $2A + 5B - 10D = 32$ and follow the algebra through. The result remains unchanged because $D = 0$, the only value for which $D = -D$.

Hence this 'published' solution is incorrect in that detail, even though the final answer stands.